# Microsoft Teams bots can only update the last two posts in a conversation. Is that by design?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

### Summary

- I am using the [Bot Framework REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to create and update Microsoft Teams posts.
- I have found that I can only update the last two posts of a conversation, but cannot find documentation that describes this restriction.
- It is not possible to identify the failed updates from the API response, as the HTTP response code and body is always the same, regardless of whether the update works or not (200 with the id of the "updated" activity). I would expect the response to indicate the failure, and so this appears to be a Teams bug.

### Detail

I can create conversations and create replies to conversations using the Bot Framework REST API without issue (using the [create conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation) and [send to conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-to-conversation) endpoints). My problem arises if I try to update these messages.

Given a conversation that looks like this:

```
parent_message
|_ child_message_1
|_ child_message_2
|_ child_message_3
```

If I attempt to use the [update activty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#update-activity) endpoint to update each one of these messages, I observe that:

- I can always update `parent_message`.
- I can update `child_message_3` and `child_message_2`, but *not* `child_message_1`. In each case the HTTP response is a successful HTTP response (200 response code, with a JSON body that contains the id of the updated message), regardless of whether the update succeeds or not.
- If I add another message, `child_message_4`, then this will be updatable, but `child_message_2` will no longer be updatable. I assume this is because now `child_message_2` is no longer one of the last two messages.

I see the same behavior if another user adds messages to the conversation, ie. if a user were to make two posts to the conversation I would no longer be able to update any of my own child messages as they are no longer one of the last two messages.

My questions are:

- Does anyone know if this restriction is by design? If so, can you point to some documentation on this?
- Is it possible to determine when an update fails? As mentioned, the HTTP response always reports success so I'm unable to find a way to do this. Is this a bug in Teams?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. We are able to repro this at our end and we are tracking it here: [MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs#2011](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2011)

Please follow [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2011) for updates/progress/questions.

**Updates: This is fixed.**

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, but I think the bug is different from what you think it is. Go ahead and "refresh" the conversation and you should see the updates in effect. If you're using the web app then you can refresh the page, but since you're probably using the desktop or mobile app then you could try switching to another conversation and back, or you might have to sign out and sign in again.

Comment: Sorry @KyleDelaney, but that is definitely **not** the problem I'm seeing. The messages do not update across any app (desktop/web/mobile), and are not shown after reload/refresh operations. Furthermore, when updates work correctly I see the messages updating in real-time, but when updates fail I see no changes occurring.

Comment: @Danny Smith- We were able to repro the issue that only the last two posts in the conversation gets updated. The previous ones update on refresh/reload. We have raised a bug for this. Does switching between other screens not update your older cards? If yes, please share your app manifest with us. We would look into it .

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Apologies, yes switching between channels does show the updates. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: @DannySmith - You said this is definitely not the problem you're seeing. Have you changed your mind?